# How to retain map having null values in the jackson

Tags: json, jackson

```
HashMap testMap = new HashMap();
testMap.put("Key1", "Value1");
testMap.put("Key2", null);  

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(); 
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL,JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT);          
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER,JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER,JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD,JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER,JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);          
//objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, true);

String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testMap);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

**Question:**

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, true);
```

a) When I use above statement and executes, it's throwing below exception.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Type id handling not implemented for type java.lang.Object
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.serializeWithType(JsonSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeTypedFields(MapSerializer.java:798)

objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
```

b) When I use the above statement and executes, it's working fine, but result is like below,

```
{"java.util.HashMap":{"Key1":"Value1"}}
```

But Key2 is removed from the json. So how to retain null values?

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, true);
```

c) When i usethe above statement and executes with jackson-databind.jar (version 2.7)
It working and retained null values also.
But jackson-databind version 2.7 supports jdk 7 onwards.So how can i use same thing in jdk 6 version?

Let me know any other alternatives to overcome it.

Comment: Have you tried writing custom serializer ?

Answer (score 0):

I Verified in jackson-databind.jar (version 2.7.2) with jdk 6 and working fine.